# Using js or jquery to replace w3-include-html attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[The w3 schools offers a js script to load html content inside a div using an attribute called w3-load-html.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)
I'm trying to replace the content of this attribute, but it seems JS doesn't recognize it.

```
<div id="div" w3-load-html="somecontent.html">
</div>

$("#div").attr("w3-load-html","someothercontent.html");
```

Have anyone tried this before? Or has an idea on how to achieve it.

Comment: Looks like it's working https://jsfiddle.net/81tttf2n/

Comment: Do you get some error in your console ?

Comment: @RicardoAlvaroLohmann Works for me, but shows the new content in both logs. Also, the content of the page doesn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vanilla JS, `setAttribute()` can help you out:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div');
console.log(div);

// Modify the attribute
div.setAttribute('w3-load-html', 'someother.html');
console.log(div);
```

```html
<div id="div" w3-load-html="somecontent.html"></div>
```

Comment: Somehow my console shows the new content in both logs, the content of the page doesn't change as well, inspecting the html from the console shows the same thing.